# I need a program like Microsoft silverlight?

Tags: moonlight

I'm new to using Ubuntu and I've never really heard of the program so I know nothing about it. I had regular windows when I bought this computer, but had a major file corruption and my boyfriend's uncle completely wiped my software replacing it with Ubuntu. All that aside, I really need a program that works just as well as Microsoft Silverlight for work so I can get my schedule to show up through Dayforce. I've googled somethings hoping to help, but it seemed very complicated and I am not very knowledgeable about this stuff. Can anyone explain what to look for and how do I need to install it?

Comment: Amazing how you manage to tag your question with the answer and still submit it (without noticing?)... do you even?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/moonlight) you should be able to install [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) using the package manager.